# How do I assign cover art to songs? (Archos 43)

Tags: mp3, archos-gen8, album-art

I have an [Archos 43 Internet Tablet](http://www.archos.com/products/ta/archos_43it/index.html?country=us&lang=en) running Android 2.2.
Has anyone figured out how to assign cover art to songs in the Music player?  Some of my songs work just fine, others don't.  What should I be doing to ensure that cover art displays properly in the music player?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if Archos have modified the music player at all, but on most Android devices and players, the most reliable way to ensure that all your music shows its album art in the player is to embed the album art directly in the MP3 file, rather than relying on a "folder.jpg" or a "AlbumArt.jpg" being in the folder.

As far as I know most music selling websites embed the album art directly in the file, and a lot of popular CD ripping software does too these days, so it's probably only your older files, or ones you've got from elsewhere that don't have the art embedded in the file.

I use a Windows program called [MP3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/download.html) to embed the album art directly into the file amongst other things, but there's lots of other software that will do this, see these answers on our SuperUser sister site for some suggestions: [What's the easiest way to update album art?](https://superuser.com/questions/14602/whats-the-easiest-way-to-update-album-art/30108#30108), or [Bulk fix Album artwork in iTunes library for display](https://superuser.com/questions/50690/bulk-fix-album-artwork-in-itunes-library-for-display-on-a-squeezebox-controller)