# Music covers aren't shown correctly

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-7, google-play-music, album-art

I have copied my mp3 files to my new Google Nexus 7 (Android 4.2.1) via USB into the Music folder. It can be played with *Google Play Music (version 4.5.910l.560208)*, but it is always showing one and the same cover for any track. This problem also shows up with other music players such as Rocket player. In VLC and iTunes on my PC the mp3 covers are just displayed fine!

Do I have to change something on my mp3's in order to display the covers correctly on that device or is there some kind of bug in the mp3-decoder? I couldn't find such a problem report in the web, so my assumption would be that there might be something wrong with my mp3 files.

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: It's an older question, but still pretty much holds true: [How do I assign cover art to songs?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3739/). Do your MP3 files have art embedded in them, or is there a folder.jpg or cover.jpg file in the same folder as them?

Comment: They are embedded! I usually add the cover in iTunes, save it and remove the cover.

Answer (score 3):

iTunes and Windows Media Player encode album art into the song file's metadata.  Googly Play Music uses an 'old hat' method for adding album art.  Linux or WinAmp users know about this.

In your Album directory drop the image of the album in the directory and rename as "AlbumArt.png" or "AlbumArt.jpg".  (Note the capitalization).

Google Play Music should pick it up, if not the artwork may not have fully synced.  Try resetting your droid and it should re-sync. :)

Comment: This would seem to be different behaviour to when you are using Google Play Music to stream/store music from your online library? In which case the embedded album art in the ID3 tag of the MP3 file itself appears to have priority (as it should). Only if there is no embedded album art will it look for an image file in the corresponding folder.

Comment: Capitalization is not necessary, see the official google support: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1250234

Answer (score 0):

From my experience if you want android to "forget" the old album art, you must rename the album and the artist to a new name. Adding spaces is not good enough. Example: Dancing Queen ABBA --> Dancing Queen2 ABBA2